# Disable (grey-out) some rows in a QTreeView

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.5

I have a (very simple yet) QTreeView showing some rows:

```
m_cameraModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);
QSortFilterProxyModel* cameraProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
cameraProxyModel->setSourceModel(m_cameraModel);
ui.CameraTreeView->setModel(cameraProxyModel);

m_cameraModel->appendRow(new QStandardItem("Panavision"));
m_cameraModel->appendRow(new QStandardItem("Panaflex"));
```

Here I want to disable the first row "Panavision" so that it is still visible but can't be selected any more and is somehow greyed-out so that the user can see this entry is not active.

May be this is some kind of beginner-question, but how can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to do that in the following way:

```
// Get item that corresponds to the first row
QStandardItem *item = m_cameraModel->item(0, 0);
// Disable the item.
item->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags);
```

Comment: And maybe you would like also to set the text and/or background color with the QStandardItem::setForeground() and QStandardItem::setBackground().

Comment: The Flag needed is `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` As long as that one is not set, the item will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the `QItemDelegate` class, which allows you to disable the row you want to amongst other things. There's a good question here on StackOverflow that shows how to do a very basic example: [How to set a delegate for a single cell in Qt item view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442009/how-to-set-a-delegate-for-a-single-cell-in-qt-item-view)